# How to find GUID of IE for the program?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I am developing `BHO(Browser helper object)` in order to make plugin for `IE`.

In that program I need to write `GUID` of `IE` for the program. I dont know where to find that.

I am using windows7 and `IE version 10.0.9200.16540`.

I am using this `GUID` for now

```
//GUID reference of IF

[
ComVisible(true),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352")
]
```

I am following these links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350432/BHO-Development-using-managed-code

Comment: This might be of assistance for some: http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/project-template.php

Answer (score 0):

The GUID you are using is not for IE.  It is for the interface `IObjectWithSite`.  The version of IE should not matter.  As long as you are implementing an interface with the GUID of `IObjectWithSite`, whichever version of IE you are using should be able to use your BHO.

If you want to find the GUID for such interfaces, a quick method is to scan the registry.  For example, to find the GUID of `IObjectWithSite`:

```
C:\Users\kinjal.dixit>reg query HKLM  /s /f IObjectWithSite /d

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Interface\{FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}
(Default)    REG_SZ    IObjectWithSite

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}
(Default)    REG_SZ    IObjectWithSite

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interface\{FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}
(Default)    REG_SZ    IObjectWithSite

End of search: 3 match(es) found.
```

Your output may differ, but the GUID of this interface (`IObjectWithSite`) is in the key within the `{}`.

The [command line](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx) specifies to search under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key (`HKLM`), recursively (`/s`), for the pattern 'IObjectWithSite' (`/f`), in the data only  (`/d`) (i.e. not to match keys or values).

Alternatively if you want to find out what interface a GUID refers to, you can search the registry for that pattern in the key and look at the string in the data.